# Angular controller as vm not available in $resource.$save callback function, only $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-resource

I am having an issue in AngularJS when not wanting to use $scope but a controller instead in a callback function passed to $resource.$save() as parameter.

The controller code is shown below. This code won't work as vm is undefined in the $save function's anonymous callback function. This is what I don't understand.

As you can see, there are 3 lines commented out which start with $scope.groupuploader... If I uncomment these lines and comment out the 3 lines starting with vm.groupuploader... then it does work as intended.

The flow object, by the way, stems from [ng-flow](https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow), an image upload library we are using.

Obviously, using $scope instead of vm works. But as we are trying not to use $scope anywhere we are trying to use vm instead also here.

Anyone any explanation of proposal how to solve this?

Thanks very much in advance and best regards
Sebastian

Angular Controller code:

```
angular.module('xyz')
    .controller('CreategroupController', CreategroupController);

function CreategroupController($scope, $location, BaseUrl, UserService, GroupResource) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.groupName = '';
    vm.groupDescription = '';

    vm.groupImageUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/assets/images/add_group_image_wide.png';

    // this does not work
    vm.groupuploader = {};

    // this does work
    //$scope.groupuploader = {};

    vm.create = function () {
        if (!vm.groupName) {
            return;
        }

        var newGroup = new GroupResource({name: vm.groupName, description: vm.groupDescription});
        newGroup.$save(function(newGroup) {
            // this does not work
            vm.groupuploader.flow.opts.target = BaseUrl.url + '/service/group/' + newGroup.id + '/image' + '?X-AUTH-TOKEN=' + UserService.retrieve();
            vm.groupuploader.flow.upload();

            // this does work
            //$scope.groupuploader.flow.opts.target = BaseUrl.url + '/service/group/' + newGroup.id + '/image' + '?X-AUTH-TOKEN=' + UserService.retrieve();
            //$scope.groupuploader.flow.upload();                

            $location.path('/group/' + newGroup.id + '/addmembers');
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's `vm` that is undefined and not some other part of that expression (like `vm.grouploader.flow` or `vm.grouploader.flow.opts`) that is undefined?

Comment: Indeed, your are right. I tested to log a string vm.string in the callback and that works. The flow object is undefined. Probably need to dig into the ng-flow library code...